# "We will never have the answers to everything, and God could be an answer to something, so a God may exist" as an argument against anti-theism?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, atheism

"We will never have the answers to every question and every unexplained occurrence, and a God may be involved in the explanation to the unexplained answer(s), so we cannot completely assert its non-existence."

I don't know if never having all the answers at any point is true, but let us assume that it is - there will always be a degree of incompleteness in the 'library' of knowledge we have amassed. Perhaps a conceptualization in the following way: take any event or thing we know, and repeatedly ask questions about it similar to 'how was it made' or 'how did this happen' - a form of repeated unfolding, until we arrive at a 'we don't know' or 'it's just how it's defined'

Given this premise, is it accurate, or logical, to make the subsequent argument that, since the answer to an unexplained occurrence could be God or a higher power (whatever you conceptualize it as), it is incorrect to assert that such a being cannot exist (a.k.a anti-theism).

What are your opinions of this argument?

Sounds very God-of-the-gaps-y, but my claim isn't that the existence of these gaps prove God, rather that it disproves the certainty of claiming it doesn't exist.

Side notes: Of course, if there was an unexplained question, and we eventually find a logical reason for that event occurring, it can be discounted from the set of all events God may have caused. But one of my assumptions is that this set cannot be an empty set. Moreover, you could also perform an additional unfolding of the recently discovered reason (ask it another 'why' or 'how'), and you've essentially discovered either an element of that set pre-existing, or something that can be added to the set.

Comment: No atheist who have given two thoughts about their position will ever deny that "a god may exist". But the statement is so abstract it's basically meaningless. Why should we care? There might as well be ghosts or Kardashev III civilizations in outer space, as long as I personally don't know everything there is to know I can't rule out this possibility. But if it doesn't interfere with my life why should I care? And if it does, then it's on you to explain how and prove it.

Comment: Anything you can think of might be "the answer to something," but that's not evidence that it exists.

Comment: The conclusion of the argument is not terribly committing, regardless of the argument steps. The conclusion says: "a god may exist" which seems like the argument didn't establish anything new.

Comment: The argument is a non-sequitur, it is a variant of *ad ignorantiam* fallacy called [god of the gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps), and a particularly clumsy one. What does X possibly answering some questions have to do with X's existence? Just replace "God" by "round square" and look at the conclusion. The 'logic' here reminds me the [politician's syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism): we must do something, this is something, therefore we must do it. Just replace "doing" by "answering with" and "this" by "God".

Comment: It's 2023. Why are people still debating stuff like this? There's an interesting philosophical question.

Comment: As @Conifold says, the argument is a non-sequitur, but I want to add that God of the Gaps is not an argument anyone has ever made; it is a straw man argument intended to discredit the actual arguments that theists have made.

Comment: @DavidGudeman "god of the gaps" is indeed a nickname coined by opponents of creationism, but it describes an actual trend of the creationist argument to repetitively move the goal post as they get proven wrong and fall back to yet unexplained phenomenon as a proof of god's intervention (the eponymous "gaps"). A look at the history of the creationist controversy or the career of Kent Hovind makes it pretty clear. Of course people who commit a fallacy are not the one to identify and name it, it's always their opponents. It has nothing to do with a straw man, please don't spread misinformation.

Comment: @armand, it is a straw man. The trend you described never happened.

Comment: @armand - A god of the gaps?  Rather, is not Atheism a "philosophy of the gaps"?  Most theologian scholars would avow that between the gap of Natural Theology and Systematic Theology is Historical Theology!  There is no guesswork because of the Self-revelation of God in human history, culminating in the appearance of Jesus on earth (note Christmas and Easter).  "The God of the Gaps" if I recall, was a statement by a medieval philosopher, as far as philosophers go.

Comment: @DavidGudeman so the whole Intelligent Design movement never happened? All the documentation about it, the congress hearings, the lawsuits are a fabrication? This is pure delusion and denying of reality at this point. Please come back to Earth with us.

Comment: @raygrant there is no evidence Jesus ever walked on earth, let alone that he was some kind of god. A poorly written fan-fiction is no evidence. And atheism is not a philosophy.

Comment: @armand, my point, which I've repeated several times now, is that you are producing a straw man of the ID argument. Once again, you simply restate the strawman. Your unwillingness even to acknowledge my point much less address it displays a distinct lack of intellectual integrity on your part.

Comment: @armand, You are clearly not a historian. There is more historical evidence that Jesus existed than that Julius Caesar existed. There are thousands of ancient manuscripts attesting to his life, some dating to the second century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion of the argument is not really committing, regardless of the argument steps. The conclusion says: "a god may exist", so it seems that the argument is not advancing anything new. We are no better off at the end of the argument than at the beginning.

Comment: Most philosophical (logical word gymnastics) would more correctly lead to what is accurately described as Agnosticism.  They do not deny, but they do not add facts one can bite their teeth into, either. It is a land of limbo.  The human soul seeks more certitude.

Answer (score 2):

> "We will never have the answers to every question and every unexplained occurrence, and a God may be involved in the explanation to the unexplained answer(s), so we cannot completely assert its non-existence.

We will never have the answers to every question and every unexplained occurrence, and God may not be involved at all, so we cannot completely assert its existence.

Your argument can be used to support both the existence and non-existence of God.

Comment: At least it covers both possibilities - good argument!

Comment: @ScottRowe Ignorance is bliss.